# If $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$ then show that $c\cdot\gcd(a,b)\leq\gcd(ac,bc)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> If $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$, then show that $c\cdot\gcd(a,b)\le\gcd(ac,bc)$.

My try: we know that $\gcd(ca,cb)=c\cdot \gcd(a,b)$, but here I don't know what to do.

Comment: Note that the greatest common divisor is by definition positive. What if $c$ is negative?

Comment: Just note that $\gcd(ac,bc)=|c|\gcd(a,b)\ge c\gcd(a,b)$

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong when you say $gcd(ac,bc)=c\cdot gcd(a,b)$. The correct equation is $gcd(ac,bc)=|c|\cdot gcd(a,b)$. Do you know how to prove this equation (hint: prime factorization)? From this equation the theorem follows immediately because $c\leq |c|$ holds for all $c\in\mathbb{Z}$